# How to retrieve child element of realtime database for Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a chat app, I did chat function successfully. Now, I want to prevent duplicated username. So I need child element of Datasnapshot key.

**My Firebase structure.**
[image]

I defined Firebase db in main Activity:

```
  FirebaseDatabase db;
```

in onCreate

```
db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

DatabaseReference dbref = db.getReference("Slitherio 1");
dbref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterable<DataSnapshot> keys = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
        for(DataSnapshot key :keys){

            Log.d("key",key.getValue().toString());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

`key.getValue().toString()` brings msg and name pairs.

```
01-21 19:18:57.168 15747-15747/gc.guideforslitherionohacknocheats D/key: {msg=hey, name=admin}
01-21 19:18:57.168 15747-15747/gc.guideforslitherionohacknocheats D/key: {msg=hello, name=SlitherP}
01-21 19:18:57.168 15747-15747/gc.guideforslitherionohacknocheats D/key: {msg=h, name=harry}
01-21 19:18:57.168 15747-15747/gc.guideforslitherionohacknocheats D/key: {msg=d, name=harry}
01-21 19:18:57.168 15747-15747/gc.guideforslitherionohacknocheats D/key: {msg=s, name=s}
01-21 19:18:57.168 15747-15747/gc.guideforslitherionohacknocheats D/key: {msg=d, name=d}
01-21 19:18:57.168 15747-15747/gc.guideforslitherionohacknocheats D/key: {msg=d, name=d}
01-21 19:18:57.168 15747-15747/gc.guideforslitherionohacknocheats D/key: {msg=selam, name=s}
01-21 19:18:57.168 15747-15747/gc.guideforslitherionohacknocheats D/key: {msg=ms, name=n}
```

But I want to bring just **name** of children elements.
How to retrieve **name** of children elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Message class

```
public class Message {
    private String msg;
    private String name;

    // Add getters and setters
}
```

Get value as Message

```
Message message = key.getValue(Message.class);
Log.d("key", message.getName());
```

Comment: Thank you, It is working. just edit 
message.getName() :)

Comment: Can you answer this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41808804/how-to-prevent-duplicated-uname-of-users-firebase?noredirect=1#comment70807915_41808804 
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Create a DatabaseReference in your activity:

```
DatabaseReference yourDBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("ChildName");
//If you have more than one child in your firebase database.
DatabaseReference refwithinref = yourDBRef.child("ChildName1"); 

yourDBRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapShot datasnapshot){
      String sample = datasnapshot.getValue(String.class);
      //Print the value of the child.
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+sample,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}});
```