# How to prevent duplicated uname of Users Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding username for my Chat App to Firebase Database successfully.

I implemented in activity:

```
FirebaseDatabase firedb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

in createUser Method.

```
private void createUser(String uname){
    Map<String,Object> newUser = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    newUser.put("uname",uname);
    DatabaseReference dbref = firedb.getReference();
    dbref.child("Users").push().setValue(newUser);
}
```

When user click a button this method works. This method work correctly but I want to make **uname** primary key. I do not want to add a username if it is alerady exists.

Database Structure:

[image]

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Finally, how to prevent duplicated **uname** ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294478/how-do-you-prevent-duplicate-user-properties-in-firebase

Comment: I am looking but it seems complex because I am newbie I could not understand.

Comment: I am good at SQL Database but why NoSQL is too complex? Nothing is understood easily, complex hard and feeled frusturted

Comment: The basic approach is as @AhmedAbidi answered. For more information see these answers [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29970681), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35243492), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37506003/), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38442291)

Comment: If you're looking to learn NoSQL, I recommend starting with basics. Read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and view [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a top level `/uname/` Node. Your data will be like this for example :

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "user1" : {
      "uname" : "value1",
    },
    "user2" : {
      "uname" : "value2",
    },
    "user3" : {
      "uname" : "value3",
    },
  },
  "uname" : {
    "value1": "user1",
    "value2": "user2",
    "value3": "user3",
  }
}
```

Now you have to Enforce New Data Structure:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
        "uname": { 
          ".validate": "!root.child('uname').child(newData.val()).exists()"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to add a top level uname ? Programatically or from firebase console? I am newbie for Firebase